# Gráfico com Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Estou precisando desenvolver o seguinte gráfico utilizando canvas:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém por enquanto so consegui desenhar as retas em preto representando o x,y.
Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?
Segue código feito.

1-parte html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Começando a desenhar o gráfico</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="grafico.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas_grafico" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_grafico');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //Criando nosso gráfico
    // O canto superior do gráfico deverá ficar na posição (10,10)
    // O eixo X terá 400 pixels de largura
    // O eixo Y terá 300 pixels de altura
    var grafico = new Grafico(context,20,20,400,300);


    var valores = [823, 231, 345, 500, 200, 850, 357, 699];
    grafico.colunas(valores);

    //Iremos desenhar os eixos
    // grafico.desenhaEixos();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

2- parte js

```
// arquivo: grafico.js
function Grafico(context, x, y, tamanhoX, tamanhoY) {
    //Contexto necessário para desenhar no canvas
    this.context = context;
    //Posição x e y onde o gráfico será desenhado
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //Tamanho do eixo X
    this.tamanhoX = tamanhoX;
    //Tamanho do eixo Y
    this.tamanhoY = tamanhoY;

}
Grafico.prototype = {
    //Método responsável por desenhar o eixo X
    desenhaEixoX: function() {
        this.context.strokeStyle = "black"; 
        this.context.lineWidth = 3;
        this.context.lineCap = "round";
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(this.x,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.lineTo(this.x+this.tamanhoX,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.stroke();

    },
    //Método responsável por desenhar o eixo y
    desenhaEixoY: function() {
        this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
        this.context.lineWidth = 3;
        this.context.lineCap = "round";
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(this.x,this.y );
        this.context.lineTo(this.x,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.stroke();

    },
    //Método responsável por desenhar os dois eixos
    desenhaEixos: function() {
       this.desenhaEixoX();
       this.desenhaEixoY();
    },
    //Função para fazer as colunas
    colunas: function(valores){


        }



    },
    //Retorna o código de uma cor aleatória
    corRandomica: function() {
        var letras = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var cor = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            cor += letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return cor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

é preciso preencher um array com os valores das colunas e desenhar os rectângulos.

```
<canvas id="canvas_grafico" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>

// arquivo: grafico.js
function Grafico(context, x, y, tamanhoX, tamanhoY) {
   //Contexto necessário para desenhar no canvas
   this.context = context;
    //Posição x e y onde o gráfico será desenhado
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    //Tamanho do eixo X
    this.tamanhoX = tamanhoX;
    //Tamanho do eixo Y
    this.tamanhoY = tamanhoY;
    this.colunas = [];

}
Grafico.prototype = {
    //Método responsável por desenhar o eixo X
    desenhaEixoX: function() {
        this.context.strokeStyle = "black"; 
        this.context.lineWidth = 3;
        this.context.lineCap = "round";
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(this.x,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.lineTo(this.x+this.tamanhoX,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.stroke();

    },
    //Método responsável por desenhar o eixo y
    desenhaEixoY: function() {
        this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
        this.context.lineWidth = 3;
        this.context.lineCap = "round";
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.moveTo(this.x,this.y );
        this.context.lineTo(this.x,this.y+this.tamanhoY );
        this.context.stroke();

     },
     //Método responsável por desenhar os dois eixos
     desenhaEixos: function() {
         this.desenhaEixoX();
         this.desenhaEixoY();
     },
     desenhaColunas: function() {
         var x = 0;
         var total_colunas = this.colunas.length;
         var w = this.tamanhoX / total_colunas;
         for (var i in this.colunas) {
             var val = this.colunas[i];
             var color = this.corRandomica();
             this.context.fillStyle = color;
             this.context.fillRect(x,this.tamanhoY - val,w,val);
             x += w;
         }
     },
     setColunas: function(valores){
         for (var i in valores) {
             this.colunas.push(valores[i] * this.tamanhoY / 1000);
         }
     },
     //Retorna o código de uma cor aleatória
     corRandomica: function() {
         var letras = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
         var cor = '#';
         for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
              cor += letras[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
         }
         return cor;
     }
 }

 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_grafico');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 //Criando nosso gráfico
 var grafico = new Grafico(context,0,0,500,500);

 var valores = [823, 231, 345, 500, 200, 850, 357, 699];
 grafico.setColunas(valores);
 grafico.desenhaColunas();
 grafico.desenhaEixos();
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode optar por usar o fillRect(left, top, width, height) em vez de lineTo.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('.graphic-one')
let container = document.querySelector('.cont-canvas')

let [labelSize, labelText, newLabel, labelHalf,
     barWidth, barWidthRaw, barHeight, barTop, barLeft, barHalf,
     gap,canvasWidth, canvasHeight, maxValue, divisor,
     index
    ] = [];

let dados = [300, 231, 305, 435, 730]
let colors = ['blueviolet', 'chocolate', 'blue', 'green', 'brown', 'red']
let labels = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label5", "Label5", "Label6"]
let arrLength = dados.length;
let draw = canvas.getContext("2d");

/**Funão auto-executável */
;(function barrasSet(){

    canvasWidth = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvasHeight = canvas.offsetHeight;

    barWidthRaw = canvasWidth / arrLength;
    /**Width da barra sem considerar o gap */

    barHalf = barWidthRaw / 2;
    /**50% da largura da barra */ 

    barWidth = barHalf + (barHalf / 2);
    /**Width de cada barra*/ 

    gap = barHalf * 1.9; 
    /**Distância entre uma barra e outra */

    barLeft = barHalf / 2;
    /**Left de cada barra */

    maxValue = Math.max(...dados); 
    /**Maior número do array */

    divisor = (1,11/1000) * maxValue; 
    /**1,11% de maxValue */

})();


/**Funão auto-executável */
;(function desenhaBarras(){

    dados.forEach(element => {

        index = dados.indexOf(element)/**Índece do elemento */

        barHeight = (element/100) * canvasHeight / divisor; /**Altura de cada barra */
        barTop = canvasHeight - barHeight; /**Distância do Topo */

        /**Desenha a Barra */
        draw.fillStyle = colors[index]
        draw.fillRect(barLeft, barTop, barWidth, barHeight); /**left, top, width, height */

        /**Criando a Label de cada barra */
        labelSize = 15
        labelText = labels[index]

        newLabel = document.createElement('span')
            newLabel.textContent = labelText
            newLabel.style.fontSize = `${labelSize}px`
        container.appendChild(newLabel)

        /**Pega a width da label */
        labelHalf = newLabel.offsetWidth / 2 
        container.removeChild(newLabel)

        /**Desenha a label e a posiciona*/
        draw.font =`${labelSize}px Arial`;
        draw.fillText(labelText, barLeft + (barWidth / 2) - labelHalf , barTop - 5 ) /**Texto, left, top */

        barLeft += gap;
    })
    
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Gráficos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="cont-canvas">
            <canvas class="graphic-one" width="600" height="300" style="background: rgb(211, 211, 211)">
                Navegador sem suporte para Canvas.
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).